# How to make a custom outside border for ComboBox with DropDownStyle(DropDownList)

Tags: c#, combobox, controls

i need to draw a custom outside border for ComboBox with  DropDownStyle = DropDownList when the comboBox is active for instance.
[want the combobox to appear like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZM9i.png)

i tried WndProc but it gives error in DropDownList Style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know much about combobox's styles in WinForms, but you can use System.Drawings.Graphics to do exactly what you want. Check the following code snippet:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    System.Drawing.Graphics graphics;
    System.Drawing.Rectangle rectangle;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        comboBox1.Enter += ComboBox1_Enter;
        comboBox1.Leave += ComboBox1_Leave;
    }

    private void ComboBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        graphics.Clear(this.BackColor);
    }

    private void ComboBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChangeActiveControlStyle((Control)sender);
    }

    private void ChangeActiveControlStyle(Control control)
    {
        graphics = this.CreateGraphics();          
        rectangle = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(control.Location.X -2, control.Location.Y-2, control.Width+4, control.Height+4);
        graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Yellow, rectangle);
    }
}
```